# What does "?" do? What is __FILE__?

Tags: ruby

random rails/ruby questions for a nooby, much appreciated.

Confused as to what the second '?' means in the line:

```
@page ||= params[:page].blank? ? 1 : params[:page].to_i
```

In init.rb files, what does **FILE** do really?

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "rails", "init")
```

Comment: If you've got two separate questions, have them in separate questions, even if they seem trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first ? is part of the method name, a convention used for methods that return a boolean result.

The second ? is the inline conditional operator:

```
a ? b : c
```

is equivalent to

```
if a then
  b
else
  c
end
```

---

`__FILE__` is a kernel function that returns the filename of the current file. `File.dirname(__FILE__)` would just return the directory name of the current file, and `File.join` is the same as `Array#join` with the OS specific directory seperator (`/` on Linux/OSX and `\` on Windows)

Comment: so its joining .../init_folder/rails and ../init_folder/init or?

Comment: Not so... the result will be `/init_folder/rails/init`. For example, `File.join("my", "very", "deep", "folder")` will result to `/my/very/deep/folder` or `\my\very\deep\folder`, depending on OS.

Answer (score 3):

1) It's a ternary expression, the second question mark is essentially "then", the colon after it meaning essentially "else". The whole thing could be rewritten:

```
if params[:page].blank?
  1
else
  params[:page].to_i
end
```

2) `__FILE__` is a reference to the current file, in this case `init.rb`.

Comment: ah, so the first ? is just part of the method's name, ok got it.

Comment: yup, `blank?` is the full method name.

Comment: +1 for using the correct term 'ternary'. Just a small fix : it's called the 'ternary operator' rather than 'ternary expression'.